# TFS source control - prevent a specific line from merging

Tags: tfs, version-control, branching-and-merging

I have a Dev and a Main branch of a project. They are staged at different URLs and I hold a reference to this URL in my project in a static class:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string Url = "http://staging.myurl.com";
}
```

Now the URL will be different in each branch, but I don't want the URLs overwriting each-other whenever I merge Dev->Main, or Main->Dev.

Is there a way of telling TFS that I don't want the line to be merged, or must this be done at file level instead?

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can maintain independent URLs in each branch? I don't want to use a database or a config file if I can help it. Is there a simple mechanism to facilitate this in TFS?

I have thought about wrapping the line in a pre-compile #if statement and checking for a specific build configuration, but I'm curious to know if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, you're hard-coding infrastructure concerns directly into your application, which is bad. Your application code should be environment-agnostic.

This *should* be managed via a configuration file; it's one of the canonical use-cases for it. The configuration file can either be transformed into an environment-specific version at build time (via web.config transforms), or ideally, at the time of deployment, via your deployment scripts.

There's no way to ignore specific lines. You can ignore specific *files* (via `.tfignore` for TFVC, or via `.gitignore` for Git), but you can't just tell version control to not version control a specific line of a file.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll look into a way of achieving it with .tfignore and edit my post with a solution.